# Ubercart trying to send email to blank email address

Tags: 6, ubercart, emails

I have an issue with ubercart 2.10 on Drupal 6.26 (with node-checkout 6.2 beta8) which tries to send an email a blank email address every time you remove an item from the cart. The error message received is:

```
 Unable to send e-mail. Please contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
```

I have searched online for possible answers and have not found any. I have ensured that the store email address is set and it is and user's email is set (obviously as they wouldn't have an account on the system). All the online reports of being unable to send an email has to do when check-out is completed - NOT when removing items from the cart. This problem seems to be unique to me.

Why would ubercart try to send an email when removing an item from the cart to begin with? That doesn't make sense to me.

If anyone has experienced this problem before or has any idea what could be causing it then please enlighten me as I have been bang my head on this one for a week now.

Comment: See your dblog admin/reports/dblog and tell us what it reports.

Comment: It reports that the to: mail address is blank. Which makes sense to me as we are only deleting items from the cart. That shouldn't necessitate sending an email about. I guess the question is there is some rule that could be triggering the email to be sent. I have checked the rules and they seem okay.

Comment: If you have Rules (or core Actions) enabled, make sure you use then only in logged in users.

Comment: And there is no functionality in core ubercart to send such email AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah there is no core ubercart rule to send such an email so I am a bit confused about it. Is there a way to trace what is happening?